# Boost Serialize data in a custom way

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Suppose that I've a list of objects stored somewhere in a map . My goal is to serialize all shared pointers through a key like this:

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {

template<class Archive, class T>
inline void serialize(Archive& ar, boost::shared_ptr<T>& b, const unsigned int file_version)
{
    std::string key_of_b = // get a key of object b;
    ar << key_of_b;
}

} }
```

Then, during the serialization through the key serialized, get back the object in the map. Is it possible to serialize-deserialize the object by using only the boost::shared_ptr? Like:

```
int main() {

        std::stringstream ss;

        // serialize
        boost::shared_ptr<int> p{new int{1123}};
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
        oa << p1;

        // deserialize
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
        boost::shared_ptr<int> p_i{new int{1123}};
        ia >> p_i;

        return 0;
    }
```

I know that the code cannot work in this way. I thought to handle the serialization/deserialiazion in the `serialize` method:

```
template<class Archive, class T>
    inline void serialize(Archive& ar, boost::shared_ptr<T>& b, const unsigned int file_version)
    {
        if (boost::archive::text_oarchive::is_saving::value) {
          std::string key_of_b = // get a key of object b;
          ar << key_of_b;
        } else {
          std::string key;
          ar >> key;
          // get the T
        }
    }
```

Is that correct or there is another better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're specifically talking about *certain* `T`, don't provide an overly generic `serialize` template inside the `boost` namespaces.

Instead, leverage `ADL` and put it with your custom type:

```
namespace MyLib {
    struct MyType { /*....*/ };

    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive& ar, boost::shared_ptr<MyType> const& p, unsigned)
    {
        ...
    }
    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive& ar, boost::shared_ptr<MyType>& p, unsigned)
    {
        ...
    }

    template<class Archive> inline void serialize(Archive& ar, boost::shared_ptr<MyType>& p, unsigned file_version) {
        split_free(ar, p, file_version); 
    }

} // namespace MyLib
```

About `split_free` see [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#splitting)

Comment: Sorry my error. I can have a lot of T and I cannot use a serialize method for each T.

Comment: Still, using ADL like this will avoid conflicts. You can open up the template, but keep it in the declaring namespace. Also, I think you need to rethink your approach to serialization. It feels to me like you're treating shared-pointers specially. The T's might be [fly-weight objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)? In that case, consider expressing the "flyweight" pattern explicitly (instead of "anonymous" shared_ptr usage) so you attach the semantics to that type.

Comment: That's obviously a guess, so before you point out the guess is (obviously) not accurate, generalize: the conceptual shift I suggest is to encode the semantics in custom types. (You can still use `shared_ptr` inside). As a middle-ground, you can use [serialization wrappers](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html)

Comment: Ts cannot be fly-weight objects. In any case, thank you for your help. Your solution solved the problem.